# java: Birthday probability program

Tags: java, probability

I'm trying to create a program that finds the probability of two random students in a room to have the same birthday. Number of students and number of simulations is inputted. Whenever I run it though, with 23 students, I consistently get 0.69, which is inconsistent with the actual answer of about 0.50. I think it probbaly has something to do with the fact that, if there are 3 students with the same birthday, it will count it as 3 matches. But I'm not sure how to fix this problem and I've already tried multiple times. Can I get some help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bday{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many students?");
    int num = inp.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many times?");
    int times = inp.nextInt();
    double x[] = new double[num];
    int match = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<times;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<num;j++){
            x[j] = (int)(Math.random()*365)+1;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<num;j++){
            for(int k=j+1;k<num;k++){
                if(x[j]==x[k]){
                    match++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    double prob = (double)match/times;
    System.out.println("The probability for two students to share a birthday is "+prob+".");
}}
```

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of times and what it's being used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up the logic. The logic should be like this:
whenever there is a occurrence of same birthday, you add one to the total matches and then break then start another time. After you finished all the times, divide the total matches by how many times.
here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System. in );
    System.out.println("How many students?");
    int num = inp.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How many times?");
    int times = inp.nextInt();
    int x[] = new int[num];
    int matches = 0;
    boolean out = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            x[j] = (int)(Math.random() * 365) + 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < num; k++) {
                if (x[j] == x[k]) {
                    matches++;
                    out = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (out) {
                out = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    double prob = (double) matches / times;
    System.out.println("The probability for two students to share a birthday is " + prob + ".");
}
}
```

The test result: 0.50557 for 100000, 0.507591 for 1000000. Should be close to your answer.

Comment: @josephkreifelsII the times is how many times the code will randomize the x array and calculate the probability. The total is then divided over the number of times to get average probability.